# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind' using petsc4py

Tags: python, cython

I face an error when I using a combination of petsc4py and cython:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

the bellowing code is a part of .../petsc4py/demo/wrap-cython/setup.py, a example of the project, which have an error:

```
def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
INCLUDE_DIRS = []
LIBRARY_DIRS = []
LIBRARIES    = []

# PETSc
import os
PETSC_DIR  = os.environ['PETSC_DIR']
PETSC_ARCH = os.environ.get('PETSC_ARCH', '')
from os.path import join, isdir
if PETSC_ARCH and isdir(join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH)):
    INCLUDE_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH, 'include'),
                     join(PETSC_DIR, 'include')]
    LIBRARY_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH, 'lib')]
else:
    if PETSC_ARCH: pass # XXX should warn ...
    INCLUDE_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, 'include')]
    LIBRARY_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, 'lib')]
LIBRARIES += [#'petscts', 'petscsnes', 'petscksp',
              #'petscdm', 'petscmat',  'petscvec',
              'petsc']

# PETSc for Python
import petsc4py
INCLUDE_DIRS += [petsc4py.get_include()]

# Configuration
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
config = Configuration('', parent_package, top_path)
config.add_extension('_Bratu3D',
                     sources = ['Bratu3D.pyx',
                                'Bratu3Dimpl.c'],
                     depends = ['Bratu3Dimpl.h'],
                     include_dirs=INCLUDE_DIRS + [os.curdir],
                     libraries=LIBRARIES,
                     library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS,
                     runtime_library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS)
return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

error messages are:

```
CC=/usr/local/openmpi-1.10.2/bin/mpicc F90=/usr/local/openmpi-1.10.2/bin/mpif90 LDSHARED='/usr/local/openmpi-1.10.2/bin/mpicc -fPIC  -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fvisibility=hidden -g3  -shared' \
    python setup.py -q build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 66, in <module>
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 82, in run
    self.run_command('build_src')
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 147, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources
    sources, py_files = self.filter_py_files(sources)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 389, in filter_py_files
    return self.filter_files(sources, ['.py'])
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 398, in filter_files
    (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(source)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 122, in splitext
    return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, None, extsep)
  File "/home/zhangji/anaconda3/envs/obenv/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 118, in _splitext
    sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
make: *** [Bratu3D.so] Error 1
```

Another example at .../petsc4py/demo/wrap-swig/setup.py have nearly the same code but without any error. The only exception is:

```
config.add_extension('_Bratu3D',
                     sources = ['Bratu3D.i',
                                'Bratu3D.c'],
                     depends = ['Bratu3D.h'],
                     include_dirs=INCLUDE_DIRS + [os.curdir],
                     libraries=LIBRARIES,
                     library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS,
                     runtime_library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A `list` object does not have `rfind`, a `str` object has `rfind`. You did not even show the part of code where `rfind` is used.

Comment: what should I do? THX

Comment: It would probably be useful to add the full traceback to your question. You're most likely passing a list to something that wants a string, but we have no real way of telling where.

Comment: I have add the error message, what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem with the project `petsc4py/demo/wrap-cython`

In fact the code works well with a bit of monkey patching on this file: `numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py`

The method is defined on numpy 1.11.0 as:

```
def generate_a_pyrex_source(self, base, ext_name, source, extension):
    """Pyrex is not supported, but some projects monkeypatch this method.

    That allows compiling Cython code, see gh-6955.
    This method will remain here for compatibility reasons.
    """
    return []
```

You have to override this method with your own definition. Here is the updated script tested with python 3.5.1, petsc4py 2.0.0:

**wrap-cython/setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# $ python setup.py build_ext --inplace

from numpy.distutils.command import build_src

# a bit of monkeypatching ...
import Cython.Compiler.Main
build_src.Pyrex = Cython
build_src.have_pyrex = True


def have_pyrex():
    import sys
    try:
        import Cython.Compiler.Main
        sys.modules['Pyrex'] = Cython
        sys.modules['Pyrex.Compiler'] = Cython.Compiler
        sys.modules['Pyrex.Compiler.Main'] = Cython.Compiler.Main
        return True
    except ImportError:
        return False
build_src.have_pyrex = have_pyrex

##########################
# BEGIN additionnal code #
##########################
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import appendpath
from numpy.distutils import log
from os.path import join as pjoin, dirname
from distutils.dep_util import newer_group
from distutils.errors import DistutilsError


def generate_a_pyrex_source(self, base, ext_name, source, extension):
    ''' Monkey patch for numpy build_src.build_src method
    Uses Cython instead of Pyrex.
    Assumes Cython is present
    '''
    if self.inplace:
        target_dir = dirname(base)
    else:
        target_dir = appendpath(self.build_src, dirname(base))
    target_file = pjoin(target_dir, ext_name + '.c')
    depends = [source] + extension.depends
    if self.force or newer_group(depends, target_file, 'newer'):
        import Cython.Compiler.Main
        log.info("cythonc:> %s" % (target_file))
        self.mkpath(target_dir)
        options = Cython.Compiler.Main.CompilationOptions(
            defaults=Cython.Compiler.Main.default_options,
            include_path=extension.include_dirs,
            output_file=target_file)
        cython_result = Cython.Compiler.Main.compile(source, options=options)
        if cython_result.num_errors != 0:
            raise DistutilsError("%d errors while compiling %r with Cython" % (cython_result.num_errors, source))
    return target_file

build_src.build_src.generate_a_pyrex_source = generate_a_pyrex_source
########################
# END additionnal code #
########################


def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
    INCLUDE_DIRS = []
    LIBRARY_DIRS = []
    LIBRARIES = []

    # PETSc
    import os
    PETSC_DIR = os.environ['PETSC_DIR']
    PETSC_ARCH = os.environ.get('PETSC_ARCH', '')
    from os.path import join, isdir
    if PETSC_ARCH and isdir(join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH)):
        INCLUDE_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH, 'include'),
                         join(PETSC_DIR, 'include')]
        LIBRARY_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH, 'lib')]
    else:
        if PETSC_ARCH:
            pass  # XXX should warn ...
        INCLUDE_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, 'include')]
        LIBRARY_DIRS += [join(PETSC_DIR, 'lib')]
    LIBRARIES += [  # 'petscts', 'petscsnes', 'petscksp',
        # 'petscdm', 'petscmat',  'petscvec',
        'petsc']

    # PETSc for Python
    import petsc4py
    INCLUDE_DIRS += [petsc4py.get_include()]

    # Configuration
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration('', parent_package, top_path)
    config.add_extension('Bratu3D',
                         sources=['Bratu3D.pyx', 'Bratu3Dimpl.c'],
                         depends=['Bratu3Dimpl.h'],
                         include_dirs=INCLUDE_DIRS + [os.curdir],
                         libraries=LIBRARIES,
                         library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS,
                         runtime_library_dirs=LIBRARY_DIRS)
    return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

Comment: Best answer ever! I added a file `setup_patch.py` at the highest level of my package and imported it once from a normal `setup.py` placed in the same folder and it all worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
config.ext_modules[-1] = cythonize(config.ext_modules[-1])
```

just after `config.add_extension(...)`

The issue was that `sources` ended up containing an empty list, added by [generate_a_pyrex_source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e209a18b0121fca361e6cb186076c61de4b50f3a/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py#L457). This is because it doesn't by itself know how to deal with cython files, so you need to run `cythonize` on the module to tell it how to (as demonstrated in the [cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-distutils)).

The way to figure this out for yourself is to use the python debugger. Run `python3 -m pdb setup.py -q build_ext --inplace`, type `cont` to make it run initially. You'll get the exception. You can type `up` to move up through the stack.

At the line `(base, ext) = os.path.splitext(source)` type `print(source)` to see that it's an empty list.

At the line `sources, py_files = self.filter_py_files(sources)` type `print(sources)` to see `[[], 'Bratu3Dimpl.c']`. It's then just a case of looking through `distutils/build_src.py` just before line 329 (where `self.filter_py_files` is called to see where it could have gone wrong.

Comment: I have emailed the code writer, and he said that NumPy distutils support evolved and now the code is broken. Then the setup file have been rewrote. I have tested it works well in my system. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have emailed the code writer, and he said that NumPy distutils support evolved and now the code is broken. Then the setup file have been rewrote. I have tested it works well in my system.