# Buiding with distutils gives TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython, distutils

I am trying to build the `sklearn.tree` subpackage, which includes some Cython code. I use Python 3.6.1 on Windows with Numpy 1.12.1.

The file `setup.py` (can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/setup.py)) contains distutils configuration with code such as 
`config.add_extension("_tree", sources=["_tree.pyx"],...)`

So I expect that `sources` (this variable flops through a long stack of functions listed below) is a list of strings.

However, when trying to build the package, I recieve the output listed below. It implies that the `source` in functions in the `build_src.py`, an element of `sources`, is not a string but a list.

So the questions are:

1. Did the string indeed turn into a list; if so, where?
2. Is this error caused by the way I build the module; if so, how to build it correctly?
3. Is this error caused by the way `setup.py` is written? If so, how to change it? And how did developers of sklearn use it?
4. Is this error caused by my environment? If so, what should I change?

`C:\Users\ddale\Downloads\scikit-learn-master\sklearn\tree>python setup.py build_ext
Appending tree.tests configuration to tree
Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'tree' to 'tree.tests')
running build_ext
running build_src
build_src
building extension "tree._tree" sources
Warning: Assuming default configuration (tests/{setup_tests,setup}.py was not found)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 39, in <module>
    setup(**configuration_old().todict())
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 82, in run
    self.run_command('build_src')
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 330, in build_extension_sources
    sources, py_files = self.filter_py_files(sources)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 390, in filter_py_files
    return self.filter_files(sources, ['.py'])
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 399, in filter_files
    (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(source)
  File "C:\Users\ddale\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 223, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`

Comment: Do you have the same issue when installing the whole of sklearn?

Comment: No, if I install the whole sklearn, the issue does not repeat itself.

Comment: I also found a question addressing a similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178055/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-rfind-using-petsc4py
The answer proposes a hotfix to the function
```numpy.distutils.command.build_src.build_src.generate_a_pyrex_source```. It worked for me too, but the fact of hotfix makes me uneasy.

Comment: I cannot pinpoint the exact problem and propose a fix unfortunately. I did try the subpackage build with a similar problem with Linux and Python 2.
Is there anything preventing you from building the full sklearn package?

Comment: No, the full sklearn builds OK. But I would like to play specifically with the ```tree``` module. So I want to know how to build it separately.

Comment: I could build the package as follows: change in `sklearn/tree/setup.py` the line `from numpy.distutils.core import setup` to `from setuptools import setup`. Run `cython` on the `*.pyx` files manually and then build with `python setup.py build`. The problem however is that the module `tree` makes imports to the upper hierarchichal level as `from ..base` for instance. So the resulting module is unusable.